# Every group of order $4n+2$ has a subgroup of index $2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification, fake-proofs

> Every group of order $4n+2$ has a subgroup of index $2$.

Here is what I have.

Let $G$ acts on itself with left shifts:

$$(\forall g\in G)(\forall x\in G) \quad g(x) = gx, \quad \phi: G \rightarrow S(G).$$

Then $\ker\phi = \{{\rm id}\}, \phi(G) \cong G \cong H \leq S_n.$

Let $\forall h \in H \quad\psi(h) = {\rm sign}(h), \phi(H) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong H/\ker\psi \implies |H/\ker\psi| = |H : \ker\psi| = 2$

And for isomorphism $\theta : G \rightarrow H \quad K = \theta^{-1}(\ker\psi) \leq G, |G : K| = 2$.

But I never used the fact that order $G$ is $4n+2$. What's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What is $H$? In any case, your argument doesn't appear to reference the order of $G$ at all.  So...take an example where $G$ does not have a subgroup of index $2$ and trace your argument for that group in order to spot the flaw.  You could take $G$ to be cyclic of order $3$, say.  Or even take $G$ to be trivial.

Comment: But wait: is your argument just "think about $G$ acting on itself by left multiplication and then consider the subgroup formed by the elements which yield even permutations"?  But why couldn't every element in $G$ yield an even permutation?

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write $\phi(H)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ whereas I think you should write $\psi(H)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

But why $\psi(H)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$? Why not $\psi(H)\cong 1$ i.e. $\ker(\psi)=H$ ?

Use the fact that $2\mid |G|$. So $G$ contains an element of order $2$ which is a product of $2n+1$ transpositions in $H$. Hence has sign $-1$ ....

Comment: Why is this permutation is a product of $2n + 1$ transpositions?

Comment: It is an element of order $2$ which acts on $G=\{g_1,...,g_{2(2k+1)}\}$. So it has to be $\phi(g)=(g_i g_j)...(g_o g_p)$ a product of $2k+1$ transpositions. In particular it can't fix any element of $G$. In other words if $t\in G$ and $g\in G$ with $o(g)=2$ then $g\cdot t=t'$ and $g\cdot t'=t$ hence $(t\ t')$ is one of the transpositions of $g$